# Install multiple NuGet packages error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have this problem. I want to download "`Install-Package Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face -Version 1.3.0`" but I take this error. I searched but i could not found.

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common 1.0.324'. You are trying to install this package into a p
roject that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are 
compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face -Version 1.3.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: ` Dependencies :
.NETStandard,Version=v1.1`

Comment: The message shows exactly what is the issue. You have an application that target `.net framework 4.0` but the library requires .net 4.5. So upgrade your  project to 4.5

Answer (score 0):

> Install multiple NuGet packages error

The first thing to point out is that magicandre comments pointed the right direction, "**upgrade your project to 4.5**".

**Detailed info:**

Search the nuget package `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face` on the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face/), we notice that this package have two dependencies: `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common (>= 1.0.324)` and `Newtonsoft.Json (>= 9.0.1)`:

[image]

Then manually download the dependency package `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Common (>= 1.0.324)` from nuget.org, rename it for the end of .zip, then unzip it. You will notice that package targets **.NET Standdard 1.1**.

Then according to the [compatibility list of .NET Standard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/):

[image]

So to install the package `Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face` you should **upgrade your project to .NET framwork 4.5**.